# Queuing Variable Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, foreach

I am trying to animate variables using .animate(), while the variables animate correctly, the default parameter for queuing doesn't seem to be working, meaning that all my animations play together. I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to stop these functions from running all at once.

This is my positions array, each line contains different numbers I want to animate to, each line needs to be executed separately.

```
    position: [
        {x: 1400},
        {x: 2800},
        ]
```

When my script gets to this point, it launches this function

```
function animate (varStore) {
varStore.position.forEach(function(position) {
        $({value: startingValue}).animate({value: position.x}, {
            duration: 5000,
            step: function() { 
                variableToChange = this.value;
            }
        });
});
```

It's a bit more complex than the above, however that's the most basic I can make it for readability's sake.

How can I stop this forEach loop from running again straight away and waiting until the previous animation has finished?

I've looked everywhere for a solution but I just can't seem to find anything.

I'm open to completely changing the way I'm approaching this too, I'd appreciate any suggestion on how to get this to work really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the native Javascript `setTimeout` here:

```
function animate (varStore) {
varStore.position.forEach(function(position) {
    var timer = setTimeout((function(){
        $({value: startingValue}).animate({value: position.x}, {
            duration: 5000,
            step: function() { 
                variableToChange = this.value;
            }
        });
    }), 5000);
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly, can't believe it was something so simple.
Thank you!